# Event 4012 DFSR Replication Windows 2012 server

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2

Hi there I am getting an error DFS replication event 4012 and I cant figure out how to restart it to get my DNS back up on my AD The path is C:\windows\sysvol\domain I went into the DFS tool and cant see anything on how to fix it.

Comment: Please post the full text of the event in your question.

Answer (score 1):

As per [www.eventid.net](http://www.eventid.net/display.asp?eventid=4012&eventno=11620&source=DFSR&phase=1%20www.eventid.net), try running this command on the domain controller:

```
wmic.exe /namespace:\\root\microsoftdfs path DfsrMachineConfig set MaxOfflineTimeInDays=120
```

Wait an hour for the replication to resume.